# Product of Transpositions - reflection elements of $D_5$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

In dihedral group $D_5$, there are five reflections:
$s, sr, sr^2, sr^3, sr^4.$

Q 1. The reflections are shown at:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/490089 to occur around the vertex labelled $1$ only, though had read some alternative way elsewhere.

It further correctly states:
$s_0 : (25)(34)$
$$s_0=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 &5\\ 1 & 5 & 4 & 3&2\end{pmatrix}$$

Q.2. A bigger issue is that it shows the product of transpositions to be:

$s_1= TR : (12)(53)= $
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 &5\\ 2 & 1 & 5 & 4&3\end{pmatrix}$$

But, when try to compose $s_1= TR$ find:

$R =(51234)=(12345)=$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 &5\\ 2 & 3 & 4 & 5&1\end{pmatrix}$$
$T =(25)(34)=$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 &5\\ 1 & 5 & 4 & 3&2\end{pmatrix}$$
$TR =(15)(24)=$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 &5\\ 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 &1\end{pmatrix}$$

====================================

Similarly, have issues with all other reflections' transpositions :

$s_2= TR^2 : (13)(45)$
$$s_2=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 &5\\ 3 & 2 & 1& 5&4\end{pmatrix}$$

$R^2 =(13524)=$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 &5\\ 3 & 4 & 5 & 1&2\end{pmatrix}$$
$T =(25)(34)=$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 &5\\ 1 & 5 & 4 & 3&2\end{pmatrix}$$
$TR^2 =(14)(23)=$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 &5\\ 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 &5\end{pmatrix}$$

---

$s_3= TR^3 : (14)(23)$
$$s_3 =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 &5\\ 4 & 3 & 2 & 1&5\end{pmatrix}$$

$R^3 =(14253)$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 &5\\ 4 &5 & 1&2&3 \end{pmatrix} $$
$T =(25)(34)=$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 &5\\ 1 & 5 & 4 & 3&2\end{pmatrix}$$
$TR^3 =(13)(45)=$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 &5\\ 3 & 2& 1 & 5 &4 \end{pmatrix}$$

---

$s_4 = TR^4: (15)(24)$
$$s_4 =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 &5\\ 5 & 4 & 3 & 2&1\end{pmatrix}$$

$R^4 =(15432)=$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 &5\\ 5 & 1 & 2 & 3&4 \end{pmatrix}$$
$T =(25)(34)=$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 &5\\ 1 & 5 & 4 & 3&2 \end{pmatrix}$$
$TR^4 =(12)(35)=$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 &5\\ 2 & 1 & 5 & 4 &3 \end{pmatrix}$$

==============

Edit:

My $s_1$ equals link's $s_4,$ and vice-versa.

My $s_2$ equals link's $s_3,$ and vice-versa.

Comment: I think you wrote "rotations" where you meant "reflections" up top.  The rotations are $r,r^2,r^3,r^4,e$.  What's the question btw?

Comment: Sorry.   $1$ keeps moving though.   So they're different reflections.

Comment: You just took them in a different order.  No one said they were in the same order.

Comment: @Cpc Question is why the two differ? But, on computing all; found you are correct. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: Sure thing.   They're all there.  Piece of cake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reflections in the link are all there, as you can see.   The list $s,sr,sr^2,sr^3,sr^4$ just happens to give them in a different order.

The key is that if you rotate one more time,  and then do that same reflection, $s$, the result is a reflection in a different axis.   And you can see that in the picture.

It's actually quite a trivial situation.   Because the axis gets rotated.

(Remember the pentagon always lands on itself. They're called symmetries.  So, if you will,  the original pentagon stays fixed underneath. )

Comment: Yes.
My $s_1$ equals link's $s_4,$ and vice-versa.

My $s_2$ equals link's $s_3,$ and vice-versa.

Comment: Yeah, they may have done $s,rs,r^2s$ etc.  But the point is pretty moot.

Comment: Is the reason that the link has instead done $RT, R^2T, R^3T.$? If so, Rotation is needed $n-2$ more times.

Comment: I think it's the reason.